# Variable in While Loop condition should exit loop, but doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out why this while loop is not working properly.

```
bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")

print(bday)

while True:
    if (bday != 'y' or bday != 'Y' or bday != 'n' or bday != 'N'):
        print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")
        print(bday)
        bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")
    else:
        break
```

According to my print statements, my values for "bday" are correctly seen as "y", "Y", "n", or "N". However, for some reason the condition acts as if it is the wrong value.

Originally coded as:

```
while (bday != 'y' or bday != 'Y' or bday != 'n' or bday != 'N'):
   print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")
   print(bday)
   bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The conditions in your ```if``` statement should be ```and```ed together. Currently, regardless of input, that condition will always be true.

Comment: Every string is not equal to at least one of `'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N'`. It's impossible for a string to be equal to all of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement(s) need to be `and` not `or`. Although I suggest using `not in` and a `list` and checking that to `bday.lower()`:

```
bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")

print(bday)

while True:
    if bday.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
        print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")
        print(bday)
        bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And I didn't know about `not in`, so thanks for that too it looks really useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the logic. If you want your program to ask the user again if the input is not ('y' or 'Y' or 'n' or 'N') , you have to use 'and' instead of 'or'

Try:

```
while True:
    bday = input("Has your birthday already passed? (y|n) : ")
    if ((bday != 'y') and (bday != 'Y') and (bday != 'n') and (bday != 'Y')):
        print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Do you really need so many braces? It might clean up your code a bit

Comment: Of course not. I just wrote it this way trying to explain the logic as clear as possible. In fact, the best way is using Jaba's response. :)